# Range of inputs on Blackberry's accelerometer

Tags: blackberry, mobile, range, accelerometer

I am looking at using the accelerometer as an input channel for controlling a game on the Blackberry. However, I only want to respond to it when the user makes a violent motion to the left or the right.

So my question is: what is the range of input to expect from a user holding the device in their hands and what threshold should I set to be sure I don't respond to normal movement during play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did accordingly to Marc's answer and I wrote a test that gave me the range of input. Each x, y, and z axis can have a value of -1048 to 1048 (as fas as I can tell). There is additional information on how to use the AcceleratorSensor to read these values and what they mean in the [4.7 API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/AccelerometerSensor.html).

After further testing on the device I figure that a variation of +/- 1000 in any direction within 50ms was enough to separate normal movement from a shake.

Answer (score 3):

The API docs specify that the maximum G-force acceleration that the hardware can measure is usually 2G, so if you want "violent" shaking that would be a good number to shoot for.

However, I'd highly recommend writing up a quick test app that records the values from the accelerometer and shows you the actual values it is recording (either to a log file or just keep track of the current "maximum").  Then just play around with the device and determine the best thresholds for "normal" use and "violent shaking".